# How to create a Postgres function to do the time format

Tags: postgresql

I want to change the db2 to postgres . it has DB2 function named FORMATDATE. I do not know how to do the same thing in the postgers

I tried several times to create it used postgres . it's not working/..

DB2:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.FORMATDATE(dateString CHAR(128), timeString VARCHAR(8))
  RETURNS TIMESTAMP(6)

  SPECIFIC FORMATDATE

  DETERMINISTIC

  LANGUAGE SQL

  CONTAINS SQL

  BEGIN ATOMIC

    DECLARE tmpDateStr VARCHAR(128);--
    DECLARE ret TIMESTAMP(6);--
    DECLARE year VARCHAR(4);--
    DECLARE month VARCHAR(2);--
    DECLARE day VARCHAR(2);--

    SET tmpDateStr = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(dateString,'-',''),'/',''));--

    IF (LENGTH(tmpDateStr) = 6 AND INTEGER(LEFT(tmpDateStr,2)) >= 70 ) THEN
        SET tmpDateStr = '19' || tmpDateStr;--
    END IF;--

    IF (LENGTH(tmpDateStr) = 6 AND INTEGER(LEFT(tmpDateStr,2)) < 70 ) THEN
          SET tmpDateStr = '20' || tmpDateStr;--
    END IF;--

    IF (LENGTH(tmpDateStr) != 8) THEN
      RETURN TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000');--
    END IF;--

    SET year = LEFT(tmpDateStr,4);--
    SET month = SUBSTR(tmpDateStr,5,2);--
    SET day = RIGHT(tmpDateStr,2);--

    set ret = TIMESTAMP(year || '-' || month || '-' || day || ' ' || timeString ||'.000000');--

    RETURN ret;--

END
```

It's there any better way to do it in postgres function ??

Comment: What does this `formatdate` function do? I can't find it in the DB2 documentation. Closest I found is [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_samp_dsn8duad.html) (see 02760). That's `formatdate(pattern, date)` which doesn't seem to match what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell this is old Y2K code. It's turning string dates which are possibly using 2 digit years into 4 digit years.

```
80-01-02   -> 1980-01-02
19-02-03   -> 2019-02-03
2019-02-03 -> 2019-02-03
```

It also normalizes for various delimiters and trims whitespace.

```
80/01/02   -> 1980-01-02
800102     -> 1980-01-02
```

That's easy enough. First, the normalization and trimming can be done in one go with [`translate`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to remove all /, - and spaces.

```
select translate('  80-01-02 ', '/- ', '');

 translate 
-----------
 800102
```

We could use `to_date` to fix the year and turn it into a date.

```
select case length(date_str)
when 6 then
  to_date(date_str, 'YYMMDD')
when 8 then
  to_date(date_str, 'YYYYMMDD')
end
```

But it turns out Postgres will figure it out by casting to `date`.

```
# select '20190102'::date;
    date    
------------
 2019-01-02
(1 row)

# select '190102'::date;
    date    
------------
 2019-01-02
(1 row)

# select '800102'::date;
    date    
------------
 1980-01-02
```

Putting it all together, strip the date and concatenate. Postgres will implicitly type cast the string to the return value of `timestamp`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION formatdate( date_str text, time_str text ) 
RETURNS timestamp AS 
$$
BEGIN
    date_str = translate(date_str, '/- ', '');
    return date_str || ' ' || time_str;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that there is [little point in messing about with `varchar` and `char` in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html), just use `text`.